# Can't convert from "Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>[]" to "Emgu.CV.IInputArray"

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-recognition

I'm trying to build a simple face/eye detection Windows Forms Application. I'm using latest EmguCV (4.1.0) but when I try to run the code below it gives me the title error. Second error involve the image ID's.

```
// Declaration at the beginning of the program
FaceRecognition = new EigenFaceRecognizer(80, double.PositiveInfinity); 
FaceDetection = new CascadeClassifier(//Path to .xml haarcascade file);
Faces = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
IDs = new List<int>();
Webcam = new VideoCapture(0);
Frame = new Mat();

// Some code and some code

// Image detection and feeding it into the FaceRecognizer

Webcam.Retrieve(Frame);
var imageFrame = Frame.toImage<Gray, byte>();

// Some code (checking if imageFrame might be null etc.)
if (faces.Count() > 0){
   var faces = FaceDetection.DetectMultiScale(imageFrame, 1.3, 5);
   var processedImage = imageFrame.Copy(faces[0]).Resize(128, 150, 
   Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
   Faces.Add(processedImage);
   IDs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(tbID.Text)); // ID for photo recognition (not really 
   neccesary)
}

else
{
   // First method
   var trainingFaces = (IInputArray) Faces; // Can't cast from List<Image<Gray, byte>> to IInputArray
   var trainingIDs = (IInputArray) IDs; // Can't cast from int[] to IInputArray
   FaceRecognition.Train(trainingFaces, trainingIDs);

   // Second method
   var trainingFaces = Faces.toArray();
   var trainingIDs = IDs.toArray();
   FaceRecognition.Train(trainingFaces, trainingIDs); // Can't convert from List<Image<Gray, byte>> to Emgu.CV.IInputArray.
```

Both methods give errors and I don't really know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Keep the training face images as a list of Mat

```
List<Mat> TrainingFaces = new List<Mat>();
List<int> FaceIDs = new List<int>();
```

As IInputArray could be constructed as VectorOfMat(Mat[]) or VectorOfInt(Int32)
then it can be passed as the train parameters:

```
FaceRecognition.Train( new VectorOfMat(TrainingFaces.ToArray()) , new VectorOfInt( FaceIDs.ToArray()) );
```

Comment: I have a list of Image<Gray, byte>, how do i convert it to IInputArray?

Comment: An OpenCV Image has Mat header in it. You can get the Mat object with _image.Mat;

Answer (score 2):

It is of course true that you can go back to an old version to make it work but that is not the solution to the problem.
To begin with we all know that EmguCV is an OpenCV Wrapper. the Train method derives from the FaceRecognizer class and must receive two arguments: a first of type IInputArrayOfArrays which includes the previously recorded images and a second argument of type IInputArray which includes the labels.
the error comes from the fact that you give this method image lists while in the definition of the method (which you can see by decompiling the faceRecognizer class) you have to give it the two aforementioned types. How to solve?
I bet you already have the following two lists in the attributes of your class:

```
List<Image<Gray, byte>> TrainedFaces = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
List<int> PersonsLabes = new List<int>();
```

**STEP 1 :**
You have to convert these two lists into arrays by doing:

```
Image<Gray, Byte>[] Faces = TrainedFaces.ToArray();
int[] labels = PersonsLabes.ToArray();
```

**2nd step:**
You declare two variables of types VectorOfMat and VectorOfInt (all these two types come from the namespace Emgu.CV.Util) as follows:

```
VectorOfMat vectorOfMat = new VectorOfMat();
VectorOfInt vectorOfInt = new VectorOfInt();
```

Step 3:
Dump the elements of your arrays from step 1 into these new vectors by doing:

```
vectorOfMat.Push(Faces);
vectorOfInt.Push(labels);
```

**Step 4 and the last:**
You pass these two vectors to your EigenFaceRecognizer object as follows:

```
EigenFaceRecognizer recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(ImagesCount, Threshold);
recognizer. Train(vectorOfMat, vectorOfInt);
```

[This Pic can Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqxiQ.png)

here is the complete code (which you must adapt according to the names assigned to your variables)

```
Image<Gray, Byte>[] Faces = TrainedFaces.ToArray();
VectorOfMat vectorOfMat = new VectorOfMat();
vectorOfMat.Push(Faces);
int[] labels = PersonsLabes.ToArray();
VectorOfInt vectorOfInt = new VectorOfInt();
vectorOfInt.Push(labels);
recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(ImagesCount, Threshold);
recognizer.Train(vectorOfMat, vectorOfInt);
```

Excuse me for my bad language, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade or downgrade your Emgu Lib

```
<package id="Emgu.CV" version="3.2.0.2721" targetFramework="net48" />
```

My Code is now working as yours Codes.