# Emgu c#, how to train list of Image<Gray, byte> in the current latest version?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have the following code

```
         var files = Directory.GetFiles("./Folder/Of/Images", "*.png");

         var trainedFaces = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();

         foreach (var f in files)
         {
             var trainedImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(f);
             trainedFaces.Add(trainedImage);
         }


         EigenFaceRecognizer recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(trainedFaces.Count, Threshold);

         recognizer.Train(trainedFaces, Enumerable.Range(1, trainedFaces.Count).ToArray());
```

from the tutorials that I watch this compiles for them but not for me because I use the latest version of Emgu for .net 6, this line

```
         recognizer.Train(trainedFaces, Enumerable.Range(1, trainedFaces.Count).ToArray());
```

causes the problem, it says `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>>' to 'Emgu.CV.IInputArray'` how do I make this work for the current version of Emgu? I literally have been searching this for hours but most would say it would compile since they use older versions of Emgu but I need the latest version since I'm forced to use .net 6

Comment: checks here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57001717/cant-convert-from-emgu-cv-imageemgu-cv-structure-gray-byte-to-emgu-cv-i

Answer (score 0):

It is of course true that you can go back to an old version to make it work but that is not the solution to the problem.
To begin with we all know that EmguCV is an OpenCV Wrapper. The Train method derives from the `FaceRecognizer` class and must receive two arguments: a first of type `IInputArrayOfArrays` which includes the previously recorded images and a second argument of type `IInputArray` which includes the labels.

The error comes from the fact that you give this method image lists while in the definition of the method (which you can see by decompiling the `FaceRecognizer` class) you have to give it the two aforementioned types. How to solve?

I bet you already have the following two lists in the attributes of your class:

```
List<Image<Gray, byte>> TrainedFaces = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
List<int> PersonsLabes = new List<int>();
```

**STEP 1 :**
You have to convert these two lists into arrays by doing:

```
Image<Gray, Byte>[] Faces = TrainedFaces.ToArray();
int[] labels = PersonsLabes.ToArray();
```

**2nd step:**
You declare two variables of types VectorOfMat and VectorOfInt (all these two types come from the namespace Emgu.CV.Util) as follows:

```
VectorOfMat vectorOfMat = new VectorOfMat();
VectorOfInt vectorOfInt = new VectorOfInt();
```

**Step 3:**
Dump the elements of your arrays from step 1 into these new vectors by doing:

```
vectorOfMat.Push(Faces);
vectorOfInt.Push(labels);
```

**Step 4 and the last:**
You pass these two vectors to your EigenFaceRecognizer object as follows:

```
EigenFaceRecognizer recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(ImagesCount, Threshold);
recognizer. Train(vectorOfMat, vectorOfInt);
```

Here is the complete code (which you must adapt according to the names assigned to your variables)

```
Image<Gray, Byte>[] Faces = TrainedFaces.ToArray();
VectorOfMat vectorOfMat = new VectorOfMat();
vectorOfMat.Push(Faces);
int[] labels = PersonsLabes.ToArray();
VectorOfInt vectorOfInt = new VectorOfInt();
vectorOfInt.Push(labels);
recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(ImagesCount, Threshold);
recognizer.Train(vectorOfMat, vectorOfInt);
```

See the picture below:

[image]

Excuse me for my bad language, Thanks !